# Bootstrap grid not working for the small screen wide < 768px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap to achieve responsiveness in different device landscapes.
But when I test this on a mobile phone, the columns are not appearing properly.  First two columns are fine, but the third column should start on the right hand side but it is pushed to the left.
[image]

The html is as follows,

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <!--required style sheets-->
    <link href="../../styles/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">    
    <link href="../../styles/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Test</title>

</head>
<body>   

    <div class="container row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">        
        </div><!--/end left column-->
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">

                        <div class="row">
                            <label class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">Reg No:</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 COES-value">21038</div>
                            <label class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">Telephone no:</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 COES-value">9758 9762</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>              
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>

    <!--javascript libraries-->
    <script src="../../js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS is as follows,

```
 /* Media queries - small #################################################      */

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {      


       .COES-value{
           font-size: 10px;
           font-family: Arial;
           font-weight: bold;
       }   

}


 /* Media queries - large #################################################      */

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {  

       .COES-value{
           font-size: 12px;
           font-family: Arial;
           font-weight: bold;
       }
}
```

Comment: there is no need to specify the nester row to be `col-*-12` (as that is the default). By nesting rows like that, you are adding spacing in between the nested rows (they have some padding themselves) so the inner elements do no have the full width anymore

Comment: I removed those  but still the same issue

Comment: I tried changing the `html` groupings... let me see if this works as you expect: http://jsfiddle.net/972nc8c7/

Comment: ochi - that works, any idea why what i proposed doesn't work?

Comment: I tried giving en explanation with my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is not related to only the iphone.
You use `labels` instead of `divs` for your grid columns. The `labels` get a `margin-bottom: 5px;` by Bootstrap's. This bottom margin makes the first column taller than the second column on the `xs` grid. For the situation that one columns become taller you should apply the Responsive column resets, see: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets

> With the four tiers of grids available you're bound to run into issues
>   where, at certain breakpoints, your columns don't clear quite right as
>   one is taller than the other. To fix that, use a combination of a
>   .clearfix and our responsive utility classes.

You nested row with the labels should look like that shown below:

```
<div class="row">
    <label class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">Reg No:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 COES-value">21038</div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
    <label class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">Telephone no:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 COES-value">9758 9762</div>
</div>
```

Also notice that you should not use the `container` and `row` class together in `<div class="container row">`, the preceding should be split up into `<div class="container"></div class="row">`.

Also there seems no need for the wrapping of the row with labels into: `<div><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">`.

Finally your code should look like that shown below:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3"></div><!--/end left column-->
        <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <div class="row">
                            <label class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">Reg No:</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 COES-value">21038</div>
                            <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
                            <label class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">Telephone no:</label>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 COES-value">9758 9762</div>
                        </div>
         </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

What happens is that within each `div` you have 12 columns in your grid.  you have four elements in a row: `label`, `div`, `label`, `div` - each with a column width of 6 if the screen size is extra small (`col-xs-6`) so you are adding 24 columns to a 12 columns space.  When that happens, the additional columns slide under.

You would expect everything to work correctly but, as you see in the image below, the internal margin of each element adds extra width to the columns and prevents the flow of the elements in their given order providing you with a misaligned grid.

[image: misalignment of elements]

To solve that, try changing your grouping as follows:

```
<div class="container row">
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    <!--/end left column-->
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <label class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">Reg No:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 COES-value">21038</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <label class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">Telephone no:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 COES-value">9758 9762</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO: Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/972nc8c7/)**

Additionally, keeping the margin to 0 for these elements may have worked as well (but you may want to narrow down the selector to affect only the fields of your choosing, otherwise it will affect all elements in any page, any location.

```
.col-sm-9 div, .col-sm-9 label{
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Resulting in :

[image: aligned elements]

Comment: your answer make no sense. But indeed setting the (bottom) margin of the label to `0` also solves the issue because that the label is not taller than the other row any more. Notice that the problem still exists when you set `label {font-size: 25px;}` or add content that flow over more than one line.

Comment: Indeed, if any element has a huge differential in line-height (or any other height setting - like min-height) it could interfere with the natural flow and alignment of the elements.